# Writing HTML Entities to a File

Tags: python, html-entities

I'm getting a UnicodeEncodeError when I run the code below. It simply loops until `i = 9000`, appends an html entity to a list based upon the value of `i`, then writes the list to a file after looping. Doe's anyone know where I'm going wrong?

```
for i in range(9000):
    list.append(html.unescape("&#" + str(i) + ";"))

open("file.txt", "w").write(", ".join(list))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default this [open method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open) doesn't support unicode, so you have to set the correct encoding for that

```
open('file.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8').write(", ".join(list))
```